# With Oracle, how can I restore a table that I dropped accidentally?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I have actually dropped instead of deleting a table in Oracle SQL.

```
Drop table emp;
```

Is there any way to retrieve it back?

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: if you're lucky and it's still in the recycle bin, you can see those in SQL Developer on your connection tree and right click to restore them...otherwise, you're going to have to ask your DBA to restore it from a backup

Comment: Done it through sqlplus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually there exists a way to retrieve back the dropped table. Please find the steps below. When you drop a table, the database does not immediately remove the space associated with the table. Instead, the table is renamed and, along with any associated objects, it is placed in the Recycle Bin of the database. The Flashback Drop operation recovers the table from the recycle bin.

Also please check if you are using oracle 10g and above too.

```
SQL> drop table vimal;

 Table dropped.

SQL> show recyclebin;
ORIGINAL NAME    RECYCLEBIN NAME                OBJECT TYPE  DROP TIME
---------------- ------------------------------ ------------ -------------------
VIMAL            BIN$c9/MeUSERvCmafRSweHlWQ==$0 TABLE        2017-01-   06:16:57:29

SQL> flashback table "BIN$c9/MeUSERvCmafRSweHlWQ==$0" to before drop;

Flashback complete.

SQL> select * from vimal;

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
f                   1
```

I request you to please read the oracle documentation for further clarification. Please go through them.

Reference can be taken from : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm

Comment: http://elena-sqldba.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-retrieve-dropped-table-in-oracle.html

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
select object_name, original_name, type from recyclebin;
```

Although the dropped table is renamed, it retains its data, you can easily "undrop" the table by using the `flashback`.

```
flashback table yourTableName to before drop;
```

Answer (score 1):

Recovering dropped table is easy in Oracle, provided that the table was not dropped with PURGE option. In case the table is dropped and space occupied by the table is released and the table does not get moved into the recycle bin. But if table is dropped without PURGE option, Oracle has this very neat feature - Recycle bin, similar to the recycle bin in Windows. There are two recyle bin views in Oracle: USER_RECYCLEBIN and DBA_RECYCLEBIN, Synonym RECYCLEBIN points to your USER_RECYCLEBIN.

http://elena-sqldba.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-retrieve-dropped-table-in-oracle.html

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_recover_dropped_table.htm

Comment: Does it have a version for Oracle (as per op's question)?

Comment: A upvote since you have given the correct reference and changed the answer.